# C++ passing a class member into another class function

Tags: c++, string, compare, strcmp

I have several classes Staff, AcademicStaff and Department(seperated header files).I have a class member AcademicStaff *headOfDepartment into Department class.I need to create a head of department.
I implemented the department then i need to set the head of the department.Also I decleared Deparment myDepartment in main.cpp.
Here is the declaretion of academic staff function.In main function I get the inputs below from the user.
`  AcademicStaff::AcademicStaff(int staffID, char *firstName, char *lastName, int telNo, char *address, char *email, int annualSalary, char *title,char *status) :
Staff(staffID, firstName, lastName, telNo, address, email, annualSalary){

```
title = new char[50];
status = new char[20];

if (strcmp(title, "Professor") == 0 || strcmp(title, "Research Professor") == 0 || strcmp(title, "Associate Professor") == 0 || strcmp(title, "Assistant Professor") == 0 || strcmp(title, "Instructor") == 0)
{
    cout << "title is defined" << endl;
    strncpy(this->title, title, 50);
    cout << "title is defined"<<endl;
}
else
    cout << "The title which is entered in not valid" << endl;`
```

I wrote a function to set the head of deppartment in Department class.

```
void setheadOfDepartment(AcademicStaff&);// in department.h`

// declaration in department.cpp 
void Department::setheadOfDepartment(AcademicStaff &professors){
    this->headOfDepartment = &professors;
}
```

---

```
/* declaration in department.h */ 
AcademicStaff *getheadOfDepartment();`
```

---

```
/* declaration in department.cpp */
AcademicStaff *Department::getheadOfDepartment(){
    return headOfDepartment;
}
```

When calling the function in `main.cpp`:

```
AcademicStaff headOfDepartment(staffID, firstName, lastName, telNo, 
                               address, email, annualSalary, 
                               title, status);
myDepartment.setheadOfDepartment(headOfDepartment);
```

when I want to get the details of Head of Department I got a value 0029fdc0.However I have to see the resuls like that : name,lastname,ıd etc.
What is the wrong things in this code?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you show an example of: (1) where you call the `setheadOfDepartment` function? and, (2) where you attempt to display these contents?

Comment: This might be a problem with the `AcademicStaff` being destructed and this giving you an invalid reference.

Comment: What do you mean by *when I want to get the details of Head of Department I got a value 0029fdc0*? Are you doing `cout << headOfDepartment`? In that case of course you will be getting an address (i.e. the pointer).

Comment: Where does the `AcademicStaff headOfDepartment(....)` variable go out of scope? Is it meant to be a class member? Is it really a function, if so where the result owned? Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, as is your question cannot be answered. You might have several design flaws in your overall code, which can't be fixed with step by step analysis of local errors.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I added some part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `AcademicSfaff` object by value to your function. The compiler creates a local copy of it, named `professors`, of which you then take the address and pass it to `this->headOfDepartment`. At the exit from the function, the temporary `professors` is being destroyed, so you end up with a dangling pointer, and all bets are off.

If you want to pass a pointer, then declare your function as taking a pointer `AcademicStaff* professors`, and pass a previously initialized pointer to it.

You are seeing an address because you probably display a pointer instead of what it points to, so you do something like

```
cout << headOfDepartment;
```

instead of

```
cout << headOfDepartment->name;
```

In any case, first fix the dangling pointer issue, which is a major problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a local copy if the parameter is passed by value:

```
Department::setheadOfDepartment(AcademicStaff professors)
```

The assignment takes the address of that copy, and not the address of what you passed in:

```
this->headOfDepartment = &professors;
```

Change your parameter signature to

```
Department::setheadOfDepartment(AcademicStaff& professors)
                                          // ^
```

pass by reference, to take the address of the originally passed variable.

Or pass a pointer parameter

```
Department::setheadOfDepartment(AcademicStaff* professors)
```

Comment: I did what you said.But ,the result is same.

Comment: @emre How do you call the function? Which of the proposed solutions did you choose? Please go [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30004613/edit) your question, to add additional information and improve it please.